# How to change style of CakePHP's invalidated fields?

Tags: validation, cakephp, styles, cakephp-2.0, invalidation

How can I change style on invalidated form fields?

I need that when user submits data on form, and if error occurs, I would like to change background color on invalidated ie. text box to red color, and not to display any error message.

Is it possible to achieve in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Invalidation should be defined in Cotroller like:

```
$this->Student->invalidate('email', false, true);
```

And new style defined like:

```
.form-control.form-error {
background-color:#790F12;
border:2px red solid;
color:#fff;
}
```

Thank you all anyway.